# changing spring jsp date input bind in a form to use freemarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I´m trying to change a spring jsp example to use freemarker.

I changed all fields in a form with something like this:
<@spring.formInput "account.name" />

Everything worked nicely. Form binded to the object and everything was validated, but I can`t get this part to work.

<@spring.formInput "account.renewalDate" />
In jsp it was

renewalDate is a java.util.Date object. The page opens and the error starts where the date input field should be.

> Method public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(java.lang.String)
>   throws java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   threw an exception when invoked on
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@1b5c22f
>   with arguments of types
>   [java.lang.String,] The problematic
>   instruction: ---------- ==>
>   assignment:
>   status=springMacroRequestContext.getBindStatus(path)
>   [on line 120, column 9 in spring.ftl]
>   in user-directive bind [on line 159,
>   column 5 in spring.ftl] in
>   user-directive spring.formInput [on
>   line 36, column 41 in createForm.ftl]
>   ---------- Java backtrace for programmers: ----------
>   freemarker.template.TemplateModelException:
>   Method public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(java.lang.String)
>   throws java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   threw an exception when invoked on
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@1b5c22f
>   with arguments of types
>   [java.lang.String,] at
>   freemarker.ext.beans.OverloadedMethodModel.exec(OverloadedMethodModel.java:134)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:90)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:603)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:603)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
>   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190)
>   at
>   freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:366)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:283)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:233)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:530)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:427)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:494)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:933)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:362)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:867)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:245)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:330)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:559)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:992)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:541)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:203)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:406)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:462)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:436)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:
>   Unable to convert value Sat Mar 05
>   15:49:22 EET 2011 from type
>   'java.util.Date' to type
>   'java.lang.String'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   JodaTime library not available -
>   @DateTimeFormat not supported at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:40)
>   at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:138)
>   at
>   org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.formatFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:122)
>   at
>   org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:227)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:120)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:726)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:840)
>   at
>   freemarker.ext.beans.OverloadedMethodModel.exec(OverloadedMethodModel.java:104)
>   ... 54 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   JodaTime library not available -
>   @DateTimeFormat not supported at
>   org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean$NoJodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.getPrinter(FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean.java:131)
>   at
>   org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean$NoJodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.getPrinter(FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean.java:1)
>   at
>   org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService$1.convert(FormattingConversionService.java:78)
>   at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:37)
>   ... 65 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the cause:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JodaTime library not available - @DateTimeFormat not supported at

Your `renewalDate` field is annotated with `@DateTimeFormat`, which doesn't work unless you add [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to the classpath.